# Recognise the sound of this glitch? (Pro Tools recording issue)

Tags: pro-tools, 003, glitch, clicks, recording

I've been doing some recording on my home studio setup and while most of the time things are running smoothly, occasionally I'll record some Foley and it sounds fine in the headphones - but when I play it back it sounds like...well, this:

http://soundcloud.com/squeakyfish/003-glitches

Does anyone recognise this particular sound or scenario? My setup is as follows:

- DAW: Pro Tools LE 8 on PC
- Surface: Digidesign Factory 003
- Mic:Cardioid microphone with 48v phantom power

Let me know if you need further specifics. Thanks in advance all!

Comment: As much as I'd never wish this particular issue on anybody, I'm glad to know that I'm not the only one whose encountered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sort of troubleshooting have you done so far? Things to try would include: different mic, different cable, different input on the 003, combinations of all three of those, route the output of your record track to a bus (and only a bus, no physical outputs) - feed that bus to an input on an aux track - and monitor the output of the aux (that way you're certain to be listening to a "post record" signal while in record). Are you recording to your OS drive, or a separate project drive? How does the audio file sound when played through Quicktime or Windows Media Player.

These are all things you can do to help narrow down where the problem is occurring, and will make your life simpler if you have to contact tech support.

Comment: Since posting this question I've tried all of the following:
- Upgraded to Pro Tool 10 (not just for this issue - I wanted some of the new features anyhow)
- Tried other mics, both phantom powered and non powered mics
- Tried other mic and line inputs
- Running a project off the C drive (normally I record and playback from an external drive)
- Played the recorded audio through a media player

With all of the above, the glitch remains.

Comment: Since upgrading to Pro Tools 10 it occurs less often, but it still happens. The short term fix is to go to Setup/Playback Engine and select and unselect "Ignore Errors During Playback/Record." But this only buys me a few extra minutes before the issue pops up again. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I should add the nature of the glitch has changed somewhat. You hear the glitch while you're recording in the headphones - the queer thing is that you can be recording and it'll start off fine...but then mid-record a clean signal suddenly becomes distorted and glitchy. 

Comment: @SqueakyFish - hmm...perplexing. i assume you updated to the latest hardware drivers before installing 10. do you have another interface you can use to test with? this might be an issue where you need to contact avid support, or visit the DUC.

Comment: I think I had the latest drivers before upgrading - I probably did that, but can't be 100% sure. I'll try my MBox and see if the issue persists using that.

Comment: Pardon the delay in replying - I'd loaned my MBox mini 3 to a friend. I've since tried out the following:
- Uninstalled/reinstalled Pro Tools 10 to no effect
- Tried installing Pro Tools 7. It's not compatible with Windows 7
- Tried re-setting the firmware on the 003, but for some reason couldn't get it to work and Pro Tools wasn't recognising the hardware
- Plugged in my Mbox mini and...recorded for 5 minutes perfectly - so it seems like the 003 is the issue

Comment: But here's where things get weird...and awesome? I plug the 003 and decide to do a test recording...and it works just fine. The test involved simultaneously recording 4 mics (different models, 3/4 of which were phantom powered) and an electric bass. In a 5 minute recording there's only one minor instance of a popping noise.

Just to be sure though, I reboot, create a new session and see if I can't replicate the same success. The results were mixed. I recorded for 7 minutes. Most of the time it sounded fine, but at the start and at the 2 minute mark there's about 30 seconds of glitchy sound.


Comment: The rest of the recording is perfect. So now it seems I can record for longer, but the effect comes again goes *while recording.*

This is a weird one. I guess I'll look at the firmware reset again.

Comment: OK, reset the firmware, but it's still running the same version of firmware anyway, so no change as expected. Now I'm going throughthe Pro Tools updates and support pages and combing through the drivers and such to make sure everything is the latest version. (Not sure if any of this is even useful or if I'm just being too detailed here!)

Comment: @SqueakyFish - sounds like it's time you contact Avid support.

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Finally got it sorted! For anyone else who has this error, you can find the solution over on the Avid forum thread here:  http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?p=2011526#post2011526

Comment: @SqeakyFish - you should post that link as its own response in the thread here. As it is right now, it's just buried in the comment. I doubt many people will see it.

Answer (score 2):

I get that on my 003 every so often when I have Analog 7-8 feeding in for SM.  Just APPLE+ 2 (numpad) to open session setup, and re-click the Clock to Internal and it goes away.  Every so often I her it start up for no reason so doing that same thing to reset the clock fixes it.  It's either a bug with the PT firmware (I never noticed it before 8.0.6) or some issue with the clock on the 003.  Not sure, my device is out of warranty and I don't feel like being nickled and dimed by Avid to get it looked into when the fix is quick (and it doesn't bother the Mains or busses, just the audio input which I hardly ever use except for Computer Audio monitoring in).

But I believe the root of the issue is somewhere with clock or how the clock is handled, and doing that command should set it straight (at least until it sneaks up again).

For what its worth, I did a lengthy post on the ProTools Ideascale and nobody gave a damn about it nor did the Avid moderators.  The DUC also turned up no info on this issue either.  Seems to be an isolated issue, maybe only with some 003 users.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot like RF interference, I have never had this problem with Pro Tools or our 003r, but I have had it with radio mics, albeit in the late 80s early 90s.  Can you recreate the problem by just recording the channel with the mic preamp turned up, but without the mic?  Until you find out what the problem is try running a second mic, ideally a dynamic, and see if you are getting the same problem.  That way you will be able to narrow down whether it is something to do with the phantom power.

Answer (score -3):

Yes i have had something like that happen to me as well with recording E-Books.I was using low latency monitoring I terned it of then back on again and it cleared up the problem. It's stupid but that's pro tools for you. Had I known this programs was as weak sauce as it is i would have got something better and for a lot less money. Pro Tools is over rated because so many die hard apple people will always defend there precious apple stuff even when it's inferior to something ells. 
Any way that's how I fixed my stupid Protools statick scratchy sounding stuff.

Comment: Pro Tools isn't owned by Apple, nor does it run only on Apple computers, and all DAWs have bugs that drive the operators nuts.

Comment: @Shaun Case in point: PT on Win 7 here

Comment: @Stavrosound - same here.